# Не подключается PHP скрипт

Tags: php

Есть файл Functions.php, в нем прописаны строки:

```
<?php $apple = 'apple'; $color = 'red'; ?>
```

Есть файл, который призывает его:

```
<?php include 'http://localhost/PhpProjectTest/Functions.php';
    echo "A $color $apple"; ?> <br />
```

Выводит просто А и все. Где ошибка? (Да, адрес прописан верно, это точно, скрипт Functions.php он находит, но почему-то не может включить код из него в код второй функции) P.S. Да, я пробовал и required и  required_once - такой же результат, только выполнение скрипта останавливается там, где происзодит ошибка.

Comment: относительный путь надо писать.... то есть если в той же папке находится файл, то будет  `<?php include 'Functions.php';` ну или что-то типа `<?php include __DIR__.'./Functions.php';`

Comment: .... Да, спасибо, это сработало. Удивительно, CSS можно и нужно так подключать, а PHP нельзя...

Comment: @DeuS7 потому, что css используется на стороне клиента, а php только на стороне сервера

Answer (score 1):

Functions.php

```
<?php $apple = 'apple'; $color = 'red'; ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php require_once('Functions.php');
    echo "A $color $apple"; ?> <br />
```